# How to generate security token for AdminProductsController in preshtashop 1.7?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

How to generate security token for AdminProductsController in preshtashop 1.7.

I am trying to get security token for AdminProductsController by using

```
Tools::getAdminToken('');
```

like `Tools::getAdminToken('AdminProductsController');`

but i'm getting error 'Invalid token', please help
thanks...

Comment: Use `Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminProducts')`

Comment: I think what @TheDrot suggested will definately work. because in `AdminProductsController` they are using `Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminProducts')`

Comment: @TheDrot it is not working it gives me 32 character key and for AdminProductsController we need 43 character key example(rYYMO2nLsQ_2BmcHvETj42MX2i6bGZlgUZ9BGNxQzGw)

Answer (score 0):

You need use: `Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminProductsController');`

Instead of: `Tools::getAdminToken('AdminProductsController');`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20841957)

Comment: @ErayBalkanli do you really believe that?, I have been very specific, their problem is that it’s trying to get the token with the wrong method.

Comment: @Rolige Then add that explanation to the question. When you just say `try this...`, it looks like you're giving a suggestion for something they could do to troubleshoot. Just a quick edit to explain that (or even better, **why**) `getAdminTokenLite` is better than `getAdminToken` would make this a great answer

Comment: No it is not working it gives me 32 character key and for AdminProductsController we need 43 character key example(rYYMO2nLsQ_2BmcHvETj42MX2i6bGZlgUZ9BGNxQzGw)